# viewLifecycleOwner is null in onActivityCreated

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-livedata

I found out when my app remains a lot of time in the background and then the user launches the app, it causes `IllegalStateException`. This exception is thrown, because `viewLifecycleOwner` is null. I wonder how that even possible?

The code looks like this: within a `Fragment`'s **`onActivityCreated`** I got:

```
val mapFragment = (childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment) as SupportMapFragment)
mapFragment.getMapAsync {
    myViewModel.someValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        doStuff()
    })
}
```

As I wrote above, `IllegalStateException` is only thrown when the app remains **a lot of time** in the recent apps.

I have no idea why, I just could suppose that there something unexpected happens when using `Google Map Fragment` (nested within a `Fragment`) with `LiveData`. Something like an issue with a complex bunch of the life cycles (Activity, Fragment, ViewModel, LiveDate, GoogleMapFragment)

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner (Fragment.java:329)
  at com.packagename.myapp.view.fragments.ObjectFragment.init (ObjectFragment.kt:69)
  at com.packagename.myapp.fragments.ObjectFragment.access$init (ObjectFragment.kt:28)
  at com.packagename.myapp.fragments.ObjectFragment$onActivityCreated$1.onMapReady (ObjectFragment.kt:58)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza (Unknown Source:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction (Unknown Source:12)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact (Unknown Source:12)
  at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:675)
  at cw.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275081@19.2.75 (100400-269183835):14)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.be.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275081@19.2.75 (100400-269183835):4)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bj.run (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275081@19.2.75 (100400-269183835):4)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: I just went a little bit dipper and find out that ``IllegalStateException`` is thrown here, because ``Fragment``'s ``getView`` is null within ``onActivityCreated``.

Comment: You cannot access `viewLifecycleOwner` before `onOnViewCreated` is called. You'll need to move your observer code out of `onActivityCreated`. See [`Fragment` source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/84448d71fda0a24ba5d60fe9368ac47b97564c88/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java#288)

Comment: @Pawel I saw the source code, though, I just cannot understand how ``onActivityCreated`` – which is called after ``onViewCreated`` – can have a null ``view``.

Comment: Well you're right... seems like the issue is coming from `getMapAsync` returning value at unknown delay. Try to change your observer body to `lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed{ doStuff() }` and see if it helps.

Comment: @Pawel I am sorry it's not clear to me what ``lifecycleScope`` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation had happened because `Activity` had been recreated by the system after being inactive for too long.

Since in that `Activity`'s `onCreate` I initialized a new instance of the `Fragment` I told in the question, I might had two `Fragment` instances at the same time. One was restored by the system and thus it got `savedInstanceState`, and the other one that was created in `Activity`'s `onCreate` by me. The last one causes problems and thus **I do not need to create a new instance of a `Fragment` when `savedInstanceState` is not null.**